# Post to remote WordPress site to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I'm using the WordPress REST API and trying to post to a remote WordPress website, but it doesn't seem to post to my 'clothes' registered custom post type.

Here's the code:

```
$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'admin:5mMcJGUGNFYq9PxU5P0ad0Np' )
),
'body' => array(
    'title'         => 'Pink Shirt',
    'status'        => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'clothes',
    'categories'    => 2,
    'slug'          => 'pink-shirt',
    'meta'          => array('amount' => '12.50', 'style' => 'petite', 'size' => 'small', 'gender' => 'ladies', 'author' => 1)
)
));
```

The post does indeed get created on the remote website, but it always ends up as a standard post (and so it appears with all the other posts), instead of the 'clothes' custom post type.

I've tried both this...

```
    'post_type' => 'clothes',
```

...and this...

```
    'type' => 'clothes',
```

...but it's the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

I've triple checked and 'clothes' is a registered post type with the `'show_in_rest'` parameter set to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/), `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` should be `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/[custom-post-type-slug-here]` instead:

> When registering a custom post type, if you want it to be available via the REST API you should set `'show_in_rest' => true` in the arguments passed to `register_post_type`. Setting this argument to true will add a route in the `wp/v2` namespace.
>
> You can optionally set the `rest_base` argument to change the base url, which will otherwise default to the post type’s name. In the example below, “books” is used as the value of `rest_base`. This will make the URL for the route `wp-json/wp/v2/books` instead of `wp-json/wp/v2/book/`, which would have been the default.

So, assuming that you're not using the `rest_base` parameter, the URL you should be using in your `POST` request is `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/clothes` instead.

Comment: Thanks - that's all great. The post now gets created with the correct post type, but now no post meta is created. It was getting created before.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot about that (which in itself should be a separate question but since we're here already let's continue.) You need to explicitly register the meta fields used by your CPT for the REST API to save its values when sending the data via `POST`: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/321304/135534. Combine the instructions from the link with what I posted here and you should be good to go @User_FTW.

Comment: Wow yes thanks that works! There's only one problem left, and that is `'categories' => 2` does not seem to work at all. I guess because it's my categories are a custom taxonomy. I won't push it here, and will take your advice to post a new question. Thanks!

Comment: In case you do have an answer to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199674/post-to-remote-wordpress-site-with-custom-taxonomy